# Сколько раз можно подключать session_start()?

Tags: php, сессия

Здравствуйте! я новичок в php. 1 раз я вызываю сессию `session_start()` при подключении к бд, 2 раз `session_start()` при регистрации  и тд, я читал, что сессию нужно вызывать каждый раз, но у меня всё находится в одном коде, так правильно? и что при этом будет происходить?

Answer (score 2):

Повторный вызов `session_start()` ни к чему не приведет. 
Если вы попробуете исполнить код

```
<?
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);

session_start();   
session_start();
```

То получите предупреждение

> Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in...

Это происходит потому что

> Сессии, использующие файлы (по умолчанию в PHP), блокируют файл сессии сразу при открытии сессии функцией session_start() или косвенно при указании session.auto_start. После блокировки, ни один другой скрипт не может получить доступ к этому же файлу сессии, пока он не будет закрыт или при завершении скрипта или при вызове функции session_write_close().

http://php.net/manual/ru/session.examples.basic.php

p.s. Первым делом старайтесь обращаться к документации. Большая часть вопросов отпадёт.

Comment: А если я создам в разных файлах сессии и потом их подключу к 1 файлу типа `session_start(); $_SESSION["steamid"] = "YES"` а в другом `session_start(); $_SESSION["login"] = "YES"` и подключу их в 1 файл, то это будет ошибкой, ведь тут 2 сессии, но 1 команда `session_start()`?

Comment: И у меня нет такой ошики **Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in...**

Comment: @АндрейБ, сессия всё равно одна. В сессии можно хранить сколько угодно переменных и любых структур данных — это обычный файл с [сериалайзом](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.serialize.php)

Comment: @Gedweb теперь ты меня убедил, спс